# Generate SOAP service with SOAP action

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, soap, apache-axis

I am new into SOAP services as I always used REST so this question may feel dumb, I just need some coaching into this technology because I don't know where to start on.

So, I have a SOAP service to be consumed by another software, and that software is showing a warning: **lack of soap action**.

As I know, the soap action is a property of the header, but at the moment my wsdl file is being generated without any header, as shown below:

```
    <wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:ns="http://foo.bar.com" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns1="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" targetNamespace="http://adomingo.gdxgroup.com">
<wsdl:documentation> Please Type your service description here </wsdl:documentation>
<wsdl:types>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://foo.bar.com">
<xs:element name="version">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence/>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="versionResponse">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="methodName">
```

What I am doing for deploying this service is to "create Web Service" right clicking in a POJO class in Eclipse (inside a dynamic web project), using Axis2 and Tomcat 9.0. When everything works i export it as a war file.

This worked until a version upgrade of the software which requires this *SOAP action* for custom web services. (Docuware 7.1)

So my question is, which technology should I be using for generating this web service with a header and its soap action?

Comment: what's your requirements? do you have the wsdl from a third party (contract first, then post your wsdl)? can you write your own service (codefirst, then post your minimal code)? ...

Comment: @josejuan I need to generate the wsdl from a java code with a war to deploy in Tomcat. We can edit the code, change the IDE, use any posible framework... we just need the header to be generated with an empty soap action.